# Angular2 + Flask: How To Change the address where angular-cli build looks up for .js files

Tags: angular, flask

I can't route the way to the files built by @angular-cli in Flask.

I can serve the files using the addresses like `http://localhost:5000/app/<filename>`, but how to teach Angular to ask server using those addresses?

Now my client app requests from server the files which are located in the 'dist' folder (like `styles.bundle.js`) directly, using suffixes `/styles.bundle.js` without adding `/app/` before the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by

1. using `ng build -d '/app/` [-d option allows to add prefix to the URL]
2. adding `@app.route('/app/<filename>'>` router to the server-side app.

But does anyone know the way to do it automatically (without adding an option to `ng build`?)

P.S. I've been working with angular only for three days:)